# How to create a catalog from LAS file in a directory with filter

Tags: lidr

With lidR package, how can I create a catalog with a filter keep_first for example?

Answer (score 1):

```
ctg = readLAScatalog("folder")
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-keep_first"
```

Whenever you will process this catalog (either with `lidR` functions or `catalog_apply`), only the first returns will be read.

Comment: thanks a lot for this explaination.

Comment: Please mark the question answered (and also this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342578/apply-a-function-to-a-catalog)